# Symfony 4 - Form returns null error

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

I'm currently working on a form and I get this error:

```
Type error: Return value of App\Entity\Customer::getGender() must be of the type string, null returned
```

Here is my code:

Short Version of the Form (CustomerFormType):

```
$builder
    ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [
            'Herr' => 'Herr',
            'Frau' => 'Frau'
        ],
        'label' => 'Anrede:',
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false
    ])

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Customer::class
    ]);
}

public function getBlockPrefix() {
    return 'app_bundle_customer_form_type';
}
```

CustomerController:

```
$form = $this->createForm(CustomerFormType::class);

$form->handleRequest($request);
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $customer = $form->getData();
    dump($customer);
}
```

Customer Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=4, nullable=false)
     */
    private $gender;
```

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: show your entity please

Comment: @PeterPopelyshko I added the entity to my question.

Comment: Your getter on `$gender` needs to have a nullable return (`public function getGender(): ?string {...}`) and `$gender` needs a way to validate (for instance, `@Assert\NotNull()`).

Comment: @JaredFarrish I just had to add the `?` after the getter methods and it worked. But what does it do?

Comment: @Dario It's specification of php 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jared Farrish in the comments, this solution works for me:

The getter on `$gender` needs to have a nullable return:

`public function getGender(): ?string`

Answer (score 1):

`$gender` should always return string, in your case, it returns null

> nullable=false

Add validation to your entity - read more about [Assert\NotNull](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotNull.html)

```
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Customer
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=4, nullable=false)
         * @Assert\NotNull()
         */
        private $gender;
```

But, as I can see you have a field named $gender - so it is better to use [choice](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html) validation like this one:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=4, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Choice({"male", "female"})
     */
    private $gender;
```

Comment: @Dario [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#the-basics-of-validation) you can read about basic validation in symfony, there are examples there

Comment: @Dario add this line `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` above the class name

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for the hint with the validation, I definitly read through the docs. But I just had to add a `?`, like JaredFarrish commented. =)

Comment: @Dario depends on your php version